# What does " we've as much" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

"So what we did, we got in touch with a nature reserve out in the country, and asked them what you could see there. And that's when we realised that we've as much, if not more wildlife than they do."

What does the sentence "And that's when we realised that we've as much, if not more wildlife than they do." really mean? Could you please rephrase it?

Especially, " that we've as much" and " if not more wildlife than they do" make me really confused.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"we've as much, if not more wildlife than they do" -> we have as much wildlife as they do, maybe even more than they do.

With a sentence such a this one, you have to look for the noun that the comparison refers to. To get the meaning, skip the "if not more" which is not immediately relevant to get the meaning of the sentence.